# execCommand("BackColor",false,"#000000") is causing my Whole Editable Iframe's Background Color TO Change!

Tags: javascript, execcommand

ok I am making a WYSIWYG editor in Javascript and I Ran Into Problems
when I execute:

```
idframe.document.execCommand("BackColor",false,"#000000");
```

My Whole Iframe's Background Color Changes to Black. Even When There Is a Selection Made by The User.
Thin only seems to happen in Firefox & Opera But Not in Internet Explorer & Chrome.This Is Kinda Weird.

Comment: Can you specify what the desired behaviour would be? What is idframe.document? Is that your iframe? If so it makes sense if the whole iframe turns black.

Comment: Yes idframe in my Iframe's name and the desierd effect is....if i execute the command stated it should make only the text's background color Black not the whole Iframe's Background. this works fine in IE or Chrome i get exectly what i want but not in Firefox or Opera

Comment: if you apply the command to the iframe it should back the background color of the iframe black. try applying it to a paragraph or span containing the text.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'hilitecolor' instead, for none IE browsers.
'BackColor' on these browsers act differently from IE. It's used to change whole document color not just selected text.